# Calculating the position of the mean, Galtonboard

Tags: probability

I have made some computer simulations which calculate the probability of an marble landing in a given bin. I saw a correlation between the probability of the marble going to, for example, left (I'll call it P(L)) and the position of the mean, which was:

P(L)*n, where n is the last bins number (meaning there are n+1 bins in total, given that the first bins number is 0). But how can I prove this mathematically?

Comment: Your simulation is that of a binomial law $B(n,p)$ with parameters $n$  (number of marbles) and $p$ (your $P(L)$) whose mean is $np$, a classical result : nothing to prove... Remark: I wouldn't speak of "Galton board" (which is reserved for the case p=1/2).

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a single marble is landing in bin (position) $k$ is

$$P(X=k)={n \choose k }\cdot p^k\cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$$

where $k\in \{0,1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and $p$ is the probability that a marble goes on the left side.

Now you can calculate $E(X)$, which is the expected position of a marble.

$$E(X)=\sum_{k=0}^n k\binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

Or just use the property of a binomial distributed random variable that it has an expected value $E(X)=n\cdot p$.